# Tikz copying node handle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using `foreach` to draw a picture, and need the node handles for the previously drawn node and the current node. Precviously I used the following pattern to save separate coordinates:

```
\node (current) {first};

\foreach \i in {...} {
    \coordinate (prev) at (current.west);
    \node (current) {\i};

    \draw[->] (prev) -- (current);
};

% There might be better solutions for this with chains or so,
% however, this is only to demonstrate the pattern
```

This becomes cumbersome rather quickly if one needs more than one coordinate from the node. Is there a method to copy the entire `nodehandle` to `prev`, so that `prev.<anchor>` (i.e. `prev.west`, `prev.east`) works?

---

MWE: As requested

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
{[every node/.style={state}]
    \node (state) [initial] {$q_0$};
    \path[->] (state) edge [loop below] ();
    \foreach \i in {1,2,n} {
        \coordinate (prev) at (state.east);
        \node (state) [right=of prev] {$q_\i$};
        \path[->] (state) edge [loop below] ();
        \path[->] (prev) edge (state);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide complete minimal working example (MWE).

Comment: I'm not sure as to what you're trying to achieve. Maybe posting some desired output might help.

Comment: @Zarko: I added a  MWE

Comment: @Alenanno: I would like to have access to the anchors of the node from the previous iteration of the foreach loop, without having to create a `coordinate` for every anchor. This is NOT about a desired output, it is a programming question: how to keep a node handle WITHOUT enumerating all the nodes drawn in the foreach loop with iteration specific names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `\pgfnodealias`, which can be used to copy the node data from one name to another:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
{[every node/.style={state}]
    \node (state) [initial] {$q_0$};
    \path[->] (state) edge [loop below] ();
    \foreach \i in {1,2,n} {
        \pgfnodealias{prev}{state}
        \node (state) [right=of prev] {$q_\i$};
        \path[->] (state) edge [loop below] ();
        \path[->] (prev) edge (state);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you need but you don't need to specify an anchor to draw a path in that fashion from one node to the other. This allows you to use variables instead of specifying anchors.

I added an extra foreach to show multiple foreach statements with different counts.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}

\tikzset{
    every node/.style={state, draw=none}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \n [count=\sft] in {3,1,5,7,2,9}{
\begin{scope}[yshift=\sft*2 cm]
\node (A) [initial] {$q_0$};
\path[->] (A) edge [loop below] ();
    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \prev (initially A)] in {1,...,\n} {
        \node (\i) [right =of \prev] {$q_\i$};
        \path[->] (\i) edge [loop below] ();
        \path[->] (\prev) edge (\i);
    }
\end{scope}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @MaartenDhondt Ahah, not even a full minute! Thanks. :D

Comment: +1 for the `remember` bit. Its just that Heiko Oberdiek's answer takes the cake by doing **exactly** what I asked for. (Although this is definitely the better solution if I need to access the nodes again after the for loop)

Comment: @ted I see. I thought you wanted to reduce the number of commands so I used a way to remove the "coordinate" command altogether. :)

Comment: @Alenanno: I think you understood me wrong: I relally like your answer, and actually used it, however, I can only accept one answer, and that has to be the other one, since that is what I would hope to find if I come here from a search engine. I _*really*_ value your solution (I learned something very useful), my post was more intended as "I like your answer, but unfortunately I can accept only one."

Comment: @ted Yeah don't worry. :D No problem. I was just saying what I thought you needed.

Answer (score 1):

Another example with `foreach` but with a pair of values denoting `previous/present` node

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
{[every node/.style={state}]
    \node (q0) [initial] {$q_0$};
    \path[->] (q0) edge [loop below] ();
    \foreach \i/\j in {0/1,1/2,2/n} {
        \node (q\j) [right=of q\i] {$q_\j$};
        \path[->] (q\j) edge [loop below] ();
        \path[->] (q\i) edge (q\j);
}    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems rather cumbersome/error prone compared to the other solutions.